# How to: Cauchy Proof

Tags: real-analysis

I feel pretty confident on proving if a sequence is Cauchy or not, but I'm not quite sure, I  understand the following proof.

Suppose $X_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ for $n\geq N$. If $\{X_n\}$ is Cauchy, prove $X_n$ is eventually constant (ie. $X_n=a$).

I know a Cauchy sequence converges, so is this asking to prove it converges to $a$?

Comment: No it is asking to prove that there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that if $n \geq n_0$ we have $X_n = a$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that $\exists\ M \in \mathbb{N}$, such that, for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x_n = a$ for all $n \geq M$.

Use the definition of Cauchy sequence: for every $\epsilon >0, \exists\ K_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_i-x_j|<\epsilon$ for all $i,j \geq K_{\epsilon}$. Take $\epsilon = 0.5$ and obtain the result.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, it is asking you to prove that for eventually the sequence take the value $a$ rather than just getting arbitrarily closed to $a$.

Hint:

$X_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, what is the smallest positive distance between two distinct integer? Try to get $\epsilon$ that is motivated from that.

Edit:

Choose $\epsilon=\frac12>0$. Since the sequence is cauchy, $\exists N >0$ , $m,n >N \implies |X_m-X_n|<\frac12.$

but $X_m, X_n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $\exists N >0$ , $m,n >N \implies |X_m-X_n|=0 $

That is for all $\exists N>0$, $x_n=X_{N+1}$.

Comment: Suppose ϵ=1/2>0. Choose N ∈ ℕ s.t for all n,m ≥N |X_n-X_m|<ϵ=1/2.               Is this what you mean? I am stil confused and feel like I'm missing a lot of information in my proof.

Comment: Yup, you are going in the right direction, if two integers, $|a-b|<0.5$, what can you conclude about $a$ and $b$? You might like to think form another direction, suppose $a$ and $b$ are not equal, can you find a lower bound for $|a-b|$?

Comment: Are they getting closer and closer to each other?

Comment: They are indeed super duper closed. Can two distinct integers have distance $0.5$ from each other?

Comment: No...right? But how do I incorporate this into my proof?

Comment: edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ..., yes (because $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete).  But the language used is actually much, much stronger.  It is asking you to show that there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $X_N = X_{N+1} = \cdots = a$.  I.e., you are asked to show that the sequence converges (and is subsequently constant) after a finite number of steps.

What happens to your Cauchy sequence when we want $|X_i - X_j| < 1$ for sufficiently large $i,j$?